# How can I view Wowza REST api docs on Ubuntu server?

Tags: rest, ubuntu, wowza

I have Wowza installed on Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS.  There is no GUI shell installed.
The Wowza REST API, it seems, can only be accessed via a file:// path and not http://
As no browser such as Chrome, Firefox, IE etc. can be run on a CLI-only interface, does anyone know how I can access the documentation, other than installing Wowza on a windows box, then configuring for the REST docs, ***solely*** for the purpose of reading the documentation?

Any clues will be greatly appreciated.

Neil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also download only the REST API documentation zip file to your client Windows machine (or any platform with a GUI browser), and have it point to the Wowza server remotely. The static web page in this zip file is more of an interface to query the REST API call methods available in a Wowza web server.

1. Download the REST API documentation zip file to your client machine, and unzip the folder.
2. Launch index.html in a browser. On the top right area, you should see a text field that contains `http://localhost:8089/api-docs` and an Explore button next to it. This field specifies the Wowza server that the page will be querying.
3. Change `localhost` to your Wowza server IP address, and click on the Explore button. If you edit index.html, you can also change the javascript that sets this URL so that you don't have to edit the text field every time.

   ```
   $(function () {
     window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
     url: "http://yourWowzaServerIP:8089/api-docs",
     ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

CD to the directory and open it in vim, emacs, or nano. It wouln't have styling or be anything fancy, but it will be able to view the text. You could also just install a light or simple webserver from NPM and serve the directory.

Comment: Thanks @Drakee510  I was using a text editor, but as you say, it doesn't have the styling.
Michelle-B 's answer below is the one that works best for me.